# usage of the term "former" to apply to the dead

Tags: meaning

I've been told that is it wrong to call FDR a "former president" as "former" means someone who is still alive who was once President,

Comment: You heard right.

Comment: "Former" seems perfectly fine to me.  The word does not mean that the person is dead, but it does not mean he's alive either.

Comment: The President of the United States is idiomatic in that most major American publications, like the New York Times, don't qualify presidents - whether alive or dead. Thus "President Trump shook hands with President Bush in front of the statue of President Lincoln." Also, some of the most formal NYT contributors will even use "Mr. Trump pointed his middle finger at Mr. Clinton," leaving out all titles

Answer (score -1):

Yup, "former" does not mean the person is dead. A better word for referring to a dead person would be "late", like " the late President".

EDIT: Thanks, Robusto. If the person has been dead for quite a while, you could just refer to him as per normal, without any "late" or "deceased" in front, as the person you are talking to should know the person you're talking about is dead.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a bit too late to say "the late president Franklin Delano Roosevelt." That is reserved for the recently deceased.

Comment: So Roosevelt is still president??

Comment: @Robusto Good point. Maybe "deceased"? Doesn't sound as respectful IMO.

Comment: @HotLicks: We should be so lucky.

Comment: @Rye123: You don't have to call any attention to the fact that historical figures are dead, except if that fact may be news to the listener. We normally don't feel obliged to specify that Julius Caesar, Jan van Eyck, Henry VIII or FDR are dead.

Comment: [I]t's [now] a bit too late to say 'the late president Franklin Delano Roosevelt.' Agreed. One can use 'the then president Franklin Delano Roosevelt' if the time has been referenced, or 'the once president Franklin Delano Roosevelt'. The latter sounds rather unusual, poetic. It is more familiar in 'The once and future king'. These words are often called 'peripheral adjectives'; 'non-semantically-predicative adjectives' is a more logical term (a future king is not a king). As the 'adjective' does not modify the noun, adjectival status is, in fact, debatable. Compare 'mere' in 'a mere youth'.

Comment: The one time you would still use "the late" for people who have been long dead is if at the time of what you describe it was a recent event, e.g. "He often visited the late FDR's family."

Comment: You can also say "As president, FDR dealt with . . . "  or "During FDR's presidency, the United States . . . "

Answer (score -1):

It does not matter whether the person is dead or alive, former means the one before the current one. Hence usage of former is perfect even if the person is dead. Even though he is now dead, he was still in the role previously and that is what matters. Cheers!

Comment: We're looking for [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score -1):

It may not be correct to refer to FDR as **"former president"** for a number of reasons.

The most important reason is that the term **"former president"** has some legal standing. See *[The Former Presidents Act.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Former_Presidents_Act)* First made law in 1958, this legislation has evolved, but never included any but living ex-presidents. Because of several government decisions as to what benefits ex-presidents might receive from the US government over the years, the term **"former president"** has been set in the minds of many to mean a living ex-president.  Possible misunderstanding would be avoided by only using the term "**former president**" to mean a living ex-president.  Uses vary, but variable uses sometimes create variable understandings.

It would be correct to refer to FDR as **President Roosevelt** when citing some action he took while president, but not before he was president. The US can have only one president at a time. FDR, having died in office, could not have acted in any way after he was president. Had FDR outlived his presidency, he would have become Mr. Roosevelt, unless addressing him directly in communication, when he would have been the **[Honorable Franklin Delano Roosevelt](http://www.formsofaddress.info/FOA_president_US_former.html).** It would be best not to call anyone **President Bush**, or **President Clinton** today, as (previously noted) there is only one president of the US at any given time. It is not correct to directly address Barack Obama as **President Obama** for the same reason.

FDR can be President Roosevelt in narration of events while he was president. Otherwise, he probably should be Mr. Roosevelt, or, just FDR.

Answer (score -2):

Another way to say "former president" or "late president" respectfully, would be to say "the late president Lincoln of 1865?" Then the sentence would imply that he was recently deceased in the year 1865. Anyone who read this sentence would henceforth know that he had passed away before 1865 or in 1865. Either way, they would know that he was still deceased in 1865.

If you were to use the word, "late" in a slightly different context, (The late president Abraham Lincoln `February 12, 1809-April 15, 1865`) then it would give more understanding to the person you may be speaking to. I agree that "former" would be grammatically incorrect and also confuse the person you are conversing with.

Comment: Welcome to English Stack Exchange @user224906, your answer doesn't actually answer the question, the original question asked if it is correct to use the word 'former' when speaking of a deceased president. Could you maybe edit the current answer such that it addresses the question more directly?